# Pythonの関数の引数に対して、動的に値を紐付けたい

Tags: python

Pythonの関数の引数に対して、動的に値を紐付けたいです。

以下のようなイメージです。

```
def sum(a,b):
    return a+b
    
sum2=sumの引数bに1を紐付けた関数

print(list(map(sum2,[1,2]))) #[2,3]
```

Javascriptだとbindで上記のことができたと記憶しておりますが、それのPython版が知りたいです。
以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sumは[組み込み関数](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/functions.html?highlight=sum#sum) としてすでに存在するので, 少し名前変えます

```py
from functools import partial
def sum2(a, b):
    return a+b

plus1 = partial(sum2, 1)

print(list(map(plus1,[1,2]))) #[2,3]
```

参考: [functools --- 高階関数と呼び出し可能オブジェクトの操作](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/functools.html)

Comment: ありがとうございます、無事解決いたしました。